# callback not working in self-repeating function

Tags: javascript

Currently I am writing a user-script which aims to insert a trailer video into the webpage. In the script I wrote a function to filter the real source for the video as the url has few kinds of format, but the callback within the function just won't work.

```
function test_url(preview,list,callback) {
if (list.length) {
    preview.src = list[0][0];
}
preview.onerror = function() {
    if (list.length) {
        test_url(preview,list);   // the function will be re-executed until the passed list is empty
    }
    else {
        console.log('No more url available!');
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") { callback(); }
        else {console.log('callback is : '+ typeof callback);}
        return;
    }
};
if (!list[0].length) {
    list.splice(0,1);
}
else {
    list[0].shift();
}}

test_url(Preview,URLs,function() {console.log('This is a callback.')})
```

The callback above won't work and it shows that `callback is undefined`.

The list passed in is like

```
[
    ['www.example1.com','www.example2.com'],
    ['www.example3.com','www.example4.com'],
    ['www.example5.com','www.example6.com']
]
```

I really don't know where the problem is as I am still a newbie to JavaScript. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: js understands that callback function belongs to `preview.onerror` function rather function test_url

Comment: You are not passing callback in this recursive call `test_url(preview,list);`

Comment: `test_url(preview,list);` There is no callback -> `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the callback to be executed.

As you are calling the `test_url` recursively, you are missing to pass the callback method to it as last parameter. So when finally your list is getting empty, at that time you have no callback method defined.

Check the code below, I've added the callback executions

```
function test_url(preview,list,callback) {
if (list.length) {
    preview.src = list[0][0];
}
preview.onerror = function() {
    if (list.length) {
        test_url(preview,list, callback); // pass the callback
    }
    else {
        console.log('No more url available!');
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") { callback(); }
        else {console.log('callback is : '+ typeof callback);}
        return;
    }
};
if (!list[0].length) {
    list.splice(0,1);
}
else {
    list[0].shift();
}
}

test_url(Preview,URLs,function() {console.log('This is a callback.')})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works perfectly.You did save my day! Can't believe I just made such a dumb mistake.

Comment: You are welcome! while I was checking your code. The complexity level is really above my head. You are calling a recursive method and then inside there is a callback invocation as well. I was wondering how deep nesting is that supposed to be.